# OpenERP in Heroku

Tags: heroku, odoo

I am new in OpenERP and in Python, but previously I have deployed a Rails app in Heroku, and it works great.

I have a Mac with an Ubuntu VM, and inside this VM, I have installed OpenERP, and it's working good.

I've been looking on the Internet how to deploy OpenERP (a ERP written in Python) on Heroku, but I haven't found anything. Do you guys know if it is possible, and where can I find a guide to do it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: why you want to host your openerp to heroku? why cant you host a openerp server

Comment: @OmaL Heroku is the unique cloud service I have used, and I thought I could use it to host OpenERP. Which cloud server do you think I should use instead of Heroku then?

Comment: @OmaL besides, Heroku is a free option.

Comment: openerp seems to have alot of  deps, it may be possible, and i did manage to get one to compile in a docker instance, but alas i have not got it to work with the outside world yet. if  you do, you may  be the first on heroku!

Comment: I've set my thoughts on this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424018/can-i-deploy-openerp-on-heroku/